# Laravel how to insert my auth user id to my database upon submission?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

im using laravel 5.4

upon submitting the form, the user_id of the submitter will be inserted in the database. and im not sure if its the right way so if you have any idea please help me thanks

can anyone help me please this my controller as of now.

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $rfq_table = $user->rfq_table;
    return view('admin.sales.rfq.index',compact('rfq_table'));
}


public function create()
{
   return view('admin.sales.rfq.create',compact('rfq_table'));
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user=Auth::user();
    $rfq= $user->rfq_table()->create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('admin.sales.rfq.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your DB looks, but you can create a var `$user_id = Auth::user()->id;` and save that in your DB

Comment: ahmm im very sorry but im kinda new in laravel, can you give me a code ? sorry for asking but if u help me with this i can do my other modules my table name is rfq_table and the userID is foreign key with the users table ID

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form, insert the session user id like this in your insert controller:

Create your variable out of the user()'s id:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

Then use the variable here:

```
$insert->usr_id = $user_id;
$insert->postcode = request('postcode');
Your Other Inserts from your submitted form go here.
```